importing among packages in python
I am Having problems understanding the import system in python.
for the sake of this question the program is structured like this:
**Demo
-- tests
____ __init__.py
---- test_1.py
---- test_2.py
-- main.py**

I have grasped the basic functioning of importing, and everything works fine when I'm working with modules within the same package.
In the above program I created a simple function inside test_2.py called hello:
def hello():
    print("hello")

and I've imported into test_1.py:
from test_2 import hello

everything works fine so far, but I get stuck when I try to import test_1.py into main.py (which is outside of the package) like this:
from tests import test_1

this throws the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_2'

Now, I understand that this error is occurring because Python reads the entire module when it is imported, therefore it tries to execute the import statement and it fails to find the path to test2 (because it is not in the same package).
I was thinking to just put all my code in one module, so I don't have to use any imports within the package and therefore the code should not break if i import that package elsewhere, but this cant be the solution...
I'm sure this is a very basic question so I've spent many hours reading python's documentation and surfing the internet, before coming here.
I've come across different importing strategies like: sys.path, importlib or PYTHONPATH, but i don't think i fully understand the concepts behind those.

You need another __init__.py file at the same level as main.py

Does this answer your question? Relative imports for the billionth time

Hello, I've read that post before and although I found it useful I don't think it solved my issue

@Riccardo The top answer should clarify how Python imports works and why there is no module named test_2 (only tests.test_2). In particular, take note of the part about how Python imports do not navigate the filesystem. from a import b doesn't mean "look for a.py in the same directory", it means "search the import path for the top-level module named a". In your project, the only top-level package tests. Every module is a submodule of that package. The module that corresponds to test_2.py is tests.test_2, which you'd import as from tests.test_2 import hello

Note that depending on whether you execute test_1.py as a script or import it asa module decides whether tests itself is visible as a package. See PEP 366 for information on getting imports correct in a module that also be executed as a script.

It's weird that
from tests import test_1

throws the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_2'

Is there a mistake? Do you want to import test_1.py or test_2.py?
Assuming you want to import test_1.py, please try:
import tests.test_1

(I'm also still a beginner in programming and in StackOverflow and this is one of my first contributions, so please don't be angry if I do something wrong, thanks!)

Not the downvoter, but just wanted to say that downvotes on this site aren't personal. They're about rating content, not people. A downvote just means that someone thought that this answer is less likely to be useful to future visitors. That can be for any number of reasons. For more on how (down)voting on this site works, see some of the related meta discussions, in particular https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/

I didn't take it personal, I just wanted to find out what I could do better next time. Thank you for the links, I'll have a look at them!

That's a great attitude to have :). Here's a few thing that could be improved to hopefully avoid downvotes in the future: 1) try to put requests for clarification in comments instead of in an answer. The reason that comments and answers are split on this site is so that future visitors don't have to wade through back-and-forth / other noise to get the the actual answer. Answers that are self-contained and to-the-point are much more useful. (I know you don't have the rep to post comments quite yet, but good to keep in mind for the future).


try to provide some explanation of how your answer works and why it's different from what the OP is doing. Answers that just say "try this code" without explaining what it's supposed to do are hard to learn from



before answering, check for duplicates. SO is a Q&A site, which is very different from a discussion forum or a personalized help site. The purpose of this site to create a searchable repository of high quality questions with high quality answers. The goal is that future visitors don't need to post a question to get the answer they need, since this information is already here. Common questions (like how imports work in Python) have been asked many times before, and we want to keep the best information on those topics centralized in one place instead of spread out over many questions.

